# parsing file in python

Tags: python, file, parsing

I'm trying to parse the 2 pipe/comma separated files and if the particular field matches in the file create the new entry in the 3rd file.

Code as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

fo = open("c-1.txt" , "r" )
for line in fo:
    #print line
    fields = line.split('|')
    src  = fields[0]

    f1 = open("Airport.txt", 'r')
    f2 = open("b.txt", "a")
    #with open('c.csv', 'r') as f1:
    #    line1 = f1.read()
    for line1 in f1:
        reader = line1.split(',')
        hi = False
        target = reader[0]
        if target == src and fields[1] == 'ZHT':
            print target
            hi = True
            f2.write(fields[0])
            f2.write("|")
            f2.write(fields[1])
            f2.write("|")
            f2.write(fields[2])
            f2.write("|")
            f2.write(fields[3])
            f2.write("|")
            f2.write(fields[4])
            f2.write("|")
            f2.write(fields[5])
            f2.write("|")
            f2.write(reader[2])
    if hi == False:
         f2.write(line)
    f2.close()
    f1.close()
fo.close()
```

The matching field gets printed 2 times in the new file. what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you show your input and a desire output?

Comment: Btw it's better to use `with open("c-1.txt" , "r") as fo:`, then you don't need to close explicitly.

Comment: Make sure you mark an answer as correct so people looking at this in the future know what helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you reset `hi` to `False` in each iteration of the loop. Lets say the second line matches, but the third does not. You set `hi` to `True` in the second line, but then to `False` again in the third, and then print the original `line`.

Try like this:

```
hi = False
for line1 in f1:
    reader = line1.split(',')
    target = reader[0]
    if target == src and fields[1] == 'ZHT':
        hi = True
        f2.write(stuff)
if hi == False:
     f2.write(line)
```

Or, assuming that only one line will ever match, you could use [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
for line1 in f1:
    reader = line1.split(',')
    target = reader[0]
    if target == src and fields[1] == 'ZHT':
        f2.write(stuff)
        break
else:
     f2.write(line)
```

Also note that you could probably replace that series of `f2.write` statements by this one, joining the several parts with `|`:

```
f2.write('|'.join(fields[0:6] + [reader[2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, you reset the flag within the loop so are liable to printing multiple lines.

If there is definitely only one row that will match it might be worth breaking the loop once that row has been found.

and finally check your data to make sure there aren't identical matching rows.

Other than that I have a couple other suggestions to clean up your code and make it easier to debug:

1) Use the `csv` library.

2) If the files can be held in memory, it would be better to hold them in memory instead of constantly opening and closing them.

3) Use `with` to handle the files (I not you have already tried in your comments).

Something like the following should work.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv

data_0 = {}

data_1 = {}

with open("c-1.txt" , "r" ) as fo, open("Airport.txt", "r") as f1:

    fo_reader = csv.reader(fo, delimiter="|")  

    f1_reader = csv.reader(f1) # default delimiter is ','

    for line in fo_reader:

        if line[1] == 'ZHT':
            try:  # Add to a list here in case keys are duplicated.
                data_0[line[0]].append(line)
            except KeyError:
                data_0[line[0]] = [line]

    for line in f1_reader:
        data_1[line[0]] = line[2]  # We only need the third column of this row to append to the data.

with open("b.txt", "a") as f2:

    writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter="|")  # I would be tempted to not make this a pipe, but probably too late already if you've got a pre-made file.

    for key in data_0:
        if key in data_1.keys():
            for row in data_0[key]:
                writer.writerow(row[:6]+data_1[key])  # index to the 6th column, and append the data from the other file.
        else:
            for row in data_0[key]:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

That should avoid having the extra rows as well as there is no true/False flag to rely on.